# Should you trust the POH in this regard?

Tags: aircraft-performance, faa-knowledge-test

The pilot's operating handbook (POH) says my take off and landing distance are 945ft and 550ft for landing.

Is it wise to increase those factors to 1000ft for safety?

Will I be penalized on the oral if the numbers are not accurate to the POH but adjusted because of safety?

These numbers are baseline numbers not taking into consideration for headwind and tailwind etc…

Answer (score 6):

Yes you'll be penalized because the question is to determine if you know how the derive the numbers from your POH, not how much additional fudge factor you think is necessary.

The examiner should specify the parameters, such as altitude, temperature and winds, and leave it to you to specify the "official" value from the POH's performance chart or table based on the parameters specified, and you'd answer that, according to the POH, for the conditions specified, the numbers are X and Y.

Then the examiner may throw a ringer in, with a follow up question like, "The runway is 950 ft, but has a significant uphill slope, not accounted for in the performance chart. Can you still go?"  That's when you'd say no, you'd want additional margin to account for the slope.

Or the examiner may say, "You're landing on a grass runway that is 575 feet, but the grass is wet and the POH only gives dry runway data or doesn't specify. Can you land safely?".  And you'd explain that wet grass has very poor braking friction (about like compacted snow) and the POH minimum is not enough.

You're not expected to know exactly how much safety margin to add when the additional information is not provided, just show that you know how to derive the performance data from what is provided, and where those sorts of follow up questions are asked, understand how conditions not accounted for in the POH can change the calculation. The examiner is looking to see if your training was reasonably comprehensive, and you can think beyond the basics.